# ASP.NET Identity LoginInfo: How long should LoginProvider and ProviderKey be?

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity

What is the maximum realistic size of the data that goes into these fields?  When customizing an Identity implementation, how large do I need to make these?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might depend on what login provider and what's the length of keys emitted by the whole provider...

I would say that 100 characters should be enough.

BTW, I wouldn't validate `LogInfo` provider/key max length at all: you should validate a min length of `1`.